# Use http-proxy-middleware to forward Express request changing only port

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

This is for a NodeJS, Express application.

I want to take a request coming into a path like
https://mycompany.com/cost-recovery -> http://mycompany.com:8447/cost-recovery. I wish to pass all headers, request bodies, etc. over to this forwarded host. Essentially the only thing I'm doing is changing the port.

I looked at http-proxy-middleware, but wasn't sure how to approach this. I wasn't sure what the router option does. Also, if there are any query strings I'm not sure they'll get passed. The problem with this service is that it doesn't look like I can take an incoming request and generate the proxy. Or at least, I don't know how. If I could, I'd build the proxy as a handler based on the incoming request.

Not looking for a full coding snippet, just a clue on what section to look for. Or if you do have an example, I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected using the `router` allows you to control how/where to proxy the request to. Note that the `target` is not needed in this case, but you need to specify it anyway, as the lib will throw an error otherwise (see this [github-issue](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/314) where this is discussed).

So, if for example you want to control where to proxy to based on the request-path, you can do the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware({
target: 'not-needed',
router: (req) => {
    if (req.path === '/cost-recovery') {
        return 'http://some-domain:1234';
    } else if (req.path === '/some-other-path') {
        return 'http://some-domain.com:5678';
    }
  }
});

const app = express();

app.use(proxyMiddleware);

app.listen(3000); // set whatever port your proxy-app should run on here
```

Comment: I like the simplicity, but I can't be certain what the host name is or the query strings. This could be deployed on a test system with a different host name.

Comment: If you want to proxy all requests regardless of the actual route, you can just remove the `/cost-recovery` context: `app.use(proxyMiddleware);` Also you can specify the router to control where to proxy to. Please, check my edit :)

Comment: I don't want to proxy all requests, those that I proxy would go to different ports (they're actually reaching different Angular containers).

Comment: Above code proxies only requests with path `/cost-recovery` to `some-domain.com:1234` and requests with path `/some-other-path` to `some-domain.com:5678`.Isn't that what you need?